# Find the intersect or nearest geo coordinates from pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial

I have lat, longs and addresses in a pandas dataframe. A user inputs an address and I'd like to lookup the details associated from pandas dataframe based on the lat, long. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_geo = pd.DataFrame({'Address': ['Addr1','Addr2','Addr3'],
                       'Value': [100, 101, 103],
                       'Lat': [33.515226, 33.51529, 33.515230],
                       'Long': [-112.094456, -112.094459, -112.094464]})
```

I geocode the address using an API and obtain a list of lat, long.

```
[33.515227, -112.094457]
```

How do I find the intersection or nearest coordinates in pandas dataframe and pull `Address` and `Value` fields? We have the geocoding API. Pandas DataFrame can be fairly large, so looking for an efficient solution using one of the python geo libraries, if possible.

Comment: You can pass each row through a method like haversine to calculate distance and put that distance in other column. Then groupby  in value and, filter on those where distance is minimum

Comment: Please also post expected output in the question.

Comment: @FaikaMajid right, that makes sense. However, I am looking for a slightly better way to do this as N can be fairly large and I'd like to avoid computing pairwise distances which can add time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`BallTree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) from `sklearn`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

df_geo = pd.DataFrame({'Address': ['Addr1','Addr2','Addr3'],
                       'Value': [100, 101, 103],
                       'Lat': [33.515226, 33.51529, 33.515230],
                       'Long': [-112.094456, -112.094459, -112.094464]})

coords = [33.515227, -112.094457]

X = np.deg2rad(df_geo[['Lat', 'Long']].values)
y = np.deg2rad(np.array([coords]))

tree = BallTree(X, leaf_size=2)
dist, ind = tree.query(y)
```

Output:

```
>>> df_geo[['Address', 'Value']].iloc[ind[0][0]].tolist()
['Addr1', 100]

>>> dist
array([[2.46826831e-08]])

>>> ind
array([[0]])
```

Comment: @kms. Let me know if this solution worked for you, please.